# Coda Filter Formula that shows all information in the filtered rows

Tags: filter, row, filtering, coda

I used this code to filter rows in a table with `Dummy Values` equal to the date tomorrow.

```
[Future Assumptions].Filter([Dummy Values]= Today()+1)
```

How it only shows one column info. I want to show all column information for a specific filtered row. How to do it in Coda?